# Dart convert every element of list

Tags: list, dart, iterable

I have a `List<String> stringValues;` that are actually numbers in quotes. I want to convert this list to `List<int> intValues`. What's an elegant way to do this?

There is `list.forEach()` that does not return anything, there is `iterable.expand()` that returns an iterable per element, there is `iterable.fold()` that returns just one element for the whole list. I could not find something that will allow me to pass each element through a closure and return another list that has the return values of the closure.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `map()` and `toList()` for this. `toList()` is necessary because `map()` returns only an `Iterable`:

```
stringValues.map((val) => int.parse(val)).toList()
```

or shorter (thanks to @AlexandreArdhuin)

```
stringValues.map(int.parse).toList()
```

[**Dartpad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e39ecd88d7ddbe87a41e55d5d8bed86b)

Comment: You can also use `stringValues.map(int.parse).toList()` as shorthand.

Comment: I always for get to do this. Thanks for the hint.